# gradle 'from' not moving files

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a project structure like so:

`root
|__ project 1
    |__ sub 1
        |__ src
            |__ main
                |__ config
        |__ build.gradle
|__ project 2 
|__ build.gradle
|__ ...`

I have a rpm building task that iterates through all subprojects and if they contain `src/main/config`, to copy it into a directory in the rpm like so:
`rootProject.subprojects {
    from (it.projectDir.name + 'src/main/config' {
        into 'conf'
    }
}`

I have tried different variations in the `from` arguments to give the path. Absolute, relative, getting the `project1/sub1/src/main/config/` as the argument. None of them seem to work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you are doing nothing  here: from and into are parts of the  **copy** task not subprojects.

There is no copy task in your script

Try something like (assuming config is a file):

```
rootProject.subprojects {
    copy() {
        from('sub1/src/main')
        into('/tmp')
        include('config')
        // rename { it + ".${name}" } -> config.subproject1 ... bof
        // better have project.config
        rename { "${name}.config" }
    }
}
```

of if a directory (which may be the case) something like:

```
   rootProject.subprojects {
        copy() {
            from ('sub1/src/main/config')
            into("/tmp/${name}-config")
        }
    }
```

Of course change `/tmp` to something that fits for you

nb: name refers to the project name, not sure it does not become ambiguous in some subtasks if you go deep. you could add : `def projectName = name` at the beginning of the subproject block and use projectName instead

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear, this is all done in a Copy task.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this works but by changing the code: 

`rootProject.subprojects {
    from (it.projectDir.name + 'src/main/config' {
        into 'conf'
    }
}`
 to 

`rootProject.subprojects {
    from (new File(it.projectDir, 'src/main/conf')) {
        into 'conf'
    }
}`

Maybe someone with more experience and expertise can explain why this works

Comment: Hey, aren't you missing a ')' after src/main/config?